Google Photos API returns TimeoutError when batchCreate is used
I am migrating my old Python 2.7 version to Python 2.10.
response = requests.post('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads', headers=headers, data=data)
works fine, but when I call
response = gphotos.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=body).execute()
I get the following exception
(<class 'TimeoutError'>, TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'), <traceback object at 0x42266b88>)
The console shows the following:

Is there anything I should fix on my side?

There are a couple of reasons you might be seeing a timeout issue.
What are the sizes of your files. Google Photos has size limits for its APIs. Make sure to validate your files before calling the APIs.
When making API requests, another option is that you can specify a longer timeout to account for potential delays in the response. For example, in Python, you can adjust the timeout parameter in requests.post() like this:
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=30)

A third option is to implement retry logic using exponential backoff when the request times out. This will help avoid transient network issues.
import time

retries = 5
for i in range(retries):
   try:
         response = gphotos.mediaItems().batchCreate(body=body).execute()
         break  # Success, exit the loop
   except TimeoutError as e:
         if i < retries - 1:
            time.sleep(2 ** i)  # Exponential backoff
         else:
            raise e  # Retries exhausted, re-raise the exception

I've had issues with Google's APIs when making mulitple requests simultaneously. try to limit the number of concurrent requests. Google APIs can rate-limit your application if it makes too many requests to quickly. Also, make sure to check your batch sizes and API quotas.
Hope this helps!
